# How to change IP of localhost into URL with XAMPP

Tags: url, xampp, localhost

I usually access my project via 127.0.0.1/*project_name* however i want to access it by only typing the project_name and not the localhost IP. Is it also possible to enter the project_name only via network? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it via adding the following line on your host file. 
Path: **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc**

## Entry on Your Machine

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1       myproject.com  #ACCESS FROM YOUR MACHINE.
```

## Entry on another machine

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
192.168.1.10    myproject.com #ACCESS FROM ANOTHER MACHINE
```

NOTE: Above will only work on the local network only. if there is any firewall you can also add it in DNS

After doing the above steps you need to configure redirect.

If you want to redirect 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1/project_name by default. configure below steps in xampp server.

### Set up Apache Redirection

Open your apache config file `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf.` Make sure the following lines are uncommented:

```
Include "conf/extra/httpd-proxy.conf"
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Open your proxy config file C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-proxy.conf. Edit it to match the following:

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
  <IfModule proxy_http_module> 
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On
    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost/project_name/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/project_name
    ProxyPreserveHost On
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

And Restart Apache OR XAMPP

Comment: when i type myproject.com on another machine it direct me to xampp dashboard.

Comment: Yes, it's because the default page on 127.0.0.1 is XAMPP dashboard, now you need to set redirect rule as mention by @Subhash. it will redirect your project page to default 127.0.0.1 page.